# Grid 960 and CSS - doesn't show in all browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, opera

I have a small problem when I test my html and css.

I'm making the HTML to a new Wordpress theme. I make the whole structure and call the CSS and JS files.

They appear in Chrome but not in other browsers. How to fix this?

[image: Chrome]

[image: Opera]

[image: Internet Explorer 8]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The first five stylesheets have type `text/javascript`, which they certainly aren't. Update them to `text/css` and it should fix the problem. Or, as [Rick Bradshaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16511/rich-bradshaw) mentions in the comments, omit the type attribute entirely. This works because the [default `type` value](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#link-type-stylesheet) for stylesheet links is `text/css`.

I also noticed that your DOCTYPE is HTML 3.2, which I highly recommend that you change. Ideally, you'd change it to the DOCTYPE defined in the [HTML 5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-link-element):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This should convince browsers to use some better-defined behaviour in these kinds of cases. However, it seems Chrome would have loaded the stylesheet even with a non-Quirks DOCTYPE, which may be a bit contrary to the [expected behaviour](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#dom-link-element).

Comment: Or, even better, just remove the type bit – the default is text/css, so there isn't much point specifying. The fact it still worked in Chrome shows that the new parser doesn't even bother to read this attribute anymore, as there aren't any other valid values.

Comment: so basicaly, i should research some more...

but thanks for help me out